# How to determine whether a point is in between two others?

Tags: javascript, math, three.js, geometry

I made a little function that doesn't work quite right...

```
function isPointbetweenTwoOthers (pA, pB, pToCheck) {
    var pApB = new THREE.Vector3();
    pApB.subVectors(pA,pB).normalize();

    var pBpA = new THREE.Vector3();
    pBpA.subVectors(pB,pA).normalize();

    var pA_pToCheck = new THREE.Vector3();
    pA_pToCheck.subVectors(pA,pToCheck).normalize();

    var pB_pToCheck = new THREE.Vector3();
    pB_pToCheck.subVectors(pB,pToCheck).normalize();

    if(pA_pToCheck.dot(pApB) <0 || pB_pToCheck.dot(pBpA) <0)
    return false
    else return true
}
```

[image]
What am I doing wrong? According to the output of my function this left above point is between the two on the right

**@Pete**
the new function:

```
function isPointBetweenTwoOthers (pA, pB, pToCheck) {
    var pApB = new THREE.Vector3();
    pApB.subVectors(pA,pB)
    var pApB_length = pApB.length()

    var pBpA = new THREE.Vector3();
    pBpA.subVectors(pB,pA)
    var pBpA_length = pBpA.length()
    var pA_pToCheck = new THREE.Vector3();
    pA_pToCheck.subVectors(pA,pToCheck)

    var pB_pToCheck = new THREE.Vector3();
    pB_pToCheck.subVectors(pB,pToCheck)

    var pToCheck_pA = new THREE.Vector3();
    pToCheck_pA.subVectors(pToCheck,pA)
    var pToCheck_pA_length = pToCheck_pA.length()

    if(pToCheck_pA_length > pBpA_length)
    {return false}
        else if(pToCheck_pA.dot(pBpA) > 0.999999 *pToCheck_pA.x*pBpA.x + pToCheck_pA.y*pBpA.y + pToCheck_pA.z*pBpA.z) 
        {return true}
        else {return false}
}
```

Now (the dark sphere in the pic below is point C) it outputs this case as true as long as I add the 0.999999 . Without it, it works fine in this case...
[image]
but in another case without the 0.9999, it tells me C is not between A & B using the following points...

```
var t1 = new THREE.Vector3(1,1,1); //A
var t2 = new THREE.Vector3(-1,1,1); //B
var t3 = new THREE.Vector3(-0.3999999999999999,1,1);  //C
```

[image]

Comment: How do you define "in between two others" here??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to calculate the vector from a point *pA* to a point *pB* then you've to subtract *pA* form *pB* *(`pB-pA`)* rather than *pB* from *pA*  *(`pA-pB`)*.
Note, [`.subVectors( a : Vector3, b : Vector3 )`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.subVectors) calculates `a-b`.

---

**Short answer**:

Verify if the distance between `pA` and `pToCheck` and the distance between `pB` and `pToCheck` is less or equal than the distance between `pA` and `pB`.
And verify if the angle between the vector form `pA` to `pToCheck` respectively `pB` to `pToCheck`and the vector from `pA` to `pB` is near to 0:

This can be done by [`.distanceTo`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.distanceTo) respectively by [`.angleTo`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.angleTo):

```js
function isPointbetweenTwoOthers (pA, pB, pToCheck) {

    let distAtoB = pA.distanceTo(pB);
    let distAtoC = pA.distanceTo(pToCheck);
    let distBtoC = pB.distanceTo(pToCheck);
    if (distAtoC > distAtoB || distBtoC > distAtoB)
        return false;

    let vAtoB = pB.clone().sub(pA);
    let vBtoA = pA.clone().sub(pB);
    let vAtoC = pToCheck.clone().sub(pA);
    let vBtoC = pToCheck.clone().sub(pB);

    let angleAC = vAtoB.angleTo(vAtoC);
    let angleBC = vBtoA.angleTo(vBtoC);
    let epsilon = 0.0017; // 0.1° in radians 
    if (Math.abs(angleAC) > epsilon || Math.abs(angleBC) > epsilon)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

---

**Long answer**:

The [Dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) between a vector *A* and a vector *B* is equal to the product of the magnitude (length) of the vectors and the cosine of the angle between the vectors.

[image]

```
A dot B == |A| * |B| * cos(alpha)
```

If the 2 vectors are [Unit vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) (normalized), then the dot product is equal to the cosine of the angle between the 2 vectors:

```non
uA = normalize(A)
uB = normalize(B)
uA dot uB == cos(alpha)
```

The cosine of an angle is grater than 0 if the angle *alpha* is in greater -90° and less than 90°, It is 0 for 90° or -90° and less than 0 else.
The cosine is 1.0 if the angle is 0° and -1.0 if the angle is 180°.

If you just want to verify if *pC* is on a line from between *pA* and *pB*, then you've to verify if the angle between vectors is 0° (or 180°) respectively the cosine of the angle is 1.0 (or -1.0).
Because of the limited accuracy of the operations you can't directly compare to 1.0. You've to verify if the cosine is grater than a value near to 1.0.
The vectors have to be normalized and use an [*epsilon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_numbers_(mathematics)) of ~0,0016 witch corresponds to the cosine of (0.1°):

```non
     pA      pC      pB
       x-------x-------x

vAtoB  |-------------->|
vAtoC  |------>|  
vBtoC          |<------|
```

```js
nvAtoB = normalize(pB-pA)
nvAtoC = normalize(pC-pA)
nvBtoC = normalize(pC-pB)

isOn = dot(nvAtoB, nvAtoC) > (1-epsilon) AND dot(nvAtoB, nvBtoC) < -(1-epsilon)
```

The function has to be:

```js
function isPointbetweenTwoOthers (pA, pB, pToCheck) {
    var nvAtoB = new THREE.Vector3();
    nvAtoB.subVectors(pB, pA).normalize();

    var nvAtoC = new THREE.Vector3();
    nvAtoC.subVectors(pToCheck, pA).normalize();

    var nvBtoC = new THREE.Vector3();
    nvBtoC.subVectors(pToCheck, pB).normalize();

    let epsilon = 0.0016;
    let cos90epsi = 1.0 - epsilon;
    return nvAtoB.dot(nvAtoC) > cos90epsi && nvAtoB.dot(nvBtoC) < -cos90epsi;
}
```

---

A different approach is to find the nearest point *pX* to *pC* on the line from *pA* to *pB*. If *pX* is between *pA* and *pB* and the distance from *pX* to *pC* is below a certain threshold, then *pC* is between *pA* to *pB*. Since *pX* is on the line defined by *pA* to *pB*, it is sufficient to compare the cosine of the angle to 0.0.

If you've a line defined by a point `O` on a unit direction vector `D`, then the intersection point `X`, can be calculated by shifting the point `O` along the line (`D`) by the distance `d`:

```
X = O + D * d
```

So the formula for the intersection point is:

```
O ... any point on the line
D ... unit vector which points in the direction of the line
P ... the "Point"

X = O + D * dot(P-O, D);
```

[image: intersection line point]

The calculation by points on the line `A`, `B` and the point `P` is:

```
D = normalize(B-A);
X = A + D * dot(P-A, D);
```

Fortunately *THREE.js* provides [`.projectOnVector()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.projectOnVector), which does the calculation of `D * dot(P-A, D)`. See also [Vector projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection):

```js
function isPointbetweenTwoOthers (pA, pB, pToCheck) {

    let vAtoB = pB.clone().sub(pA);
    let vAtoC = pToCheck.clone().sub(pA);
    let vBtoC = pToCheck.clone().sub(pB);

    // fast exit, C can't be between A and B
    if (nvAtoB.dot(nvAtoC) < 0.0 || nvAtoB.dot(nvBtoC) > 0.0)
       return false;

    // nearest point X to C on the line A, B
    let X = pA.clone().add( vAtoC.clone().projectOnVector( vAtoB ) );

    // distance between X and C
    let distXtoC = X.distanceTo( C );

    let threshold = 1.0; // ???
    return distXtoC < threshold;
}
```

---

This can be simplified further by the [Cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product). The magnitude of the cross product of 2 vectors is equal to the area of the parallelogram that the vectors span.
This means if the cross product is near to 0.0, then the vectors are parallel and *pC* is on the line from *pA* to *pB*:

```js
function isPointbetweenTwoOthers (pA, pB, pToCheck) {

    let vAtoB = pB.clone().sub(pA);
    let vAtoC = pToCheck.clone().sub(pA);
    let vBtoC = pToCheck.clone().sub(pB);

    // fast exit, C can't be between A and B
    if (nvAtoB.dot(nvAtoC) < 0.0 || nvAtoB.dot(nvBtoC) > 0.0)
       return false;

    // cross product and area spawned by the normalized vectors B-A and C-A
    let nv = vAtoB.normalize().cross(vAtoC.normalize());
    let area = nv.length();

    let epsilon = 0.0016; // ???
    return Math.abs(area) < epsilon;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To check, whether C is between A and B, calculate e.g. the vector differences `u=subVectors(pB,pA)` and `v=subVectors(pC,pA)`. Calculate the lengths of both vectors `lu` and `lv`, respectively. If `lv>lu`, return false, as C is further away from A than B is. If this is not the case, check whether the dot product of `u` and `v` equals `lu*lv` (or maybe if it is larger than `0.9999*lu*lv` to have some numerical tolerance) and return true in this case, false otherwise. Explanation: if C is not further away from A than B, and the vectors from A to B and from A to C are parallel (but not anti-parallel), the dot product is `lu*lv` ( cos(0 degrees)=1 , while cos(180 degrees, anti-parallel case)=-1 ) and C lies between A and B.

Comment: thanks Pete, but I still got some problems. I've edited the post, please take a look

Comment: I believe the final inequality check in the added code in the question should be according to Pete's answer:
`pToCheck_pA.dot(pBpA) > 0.99999 * pToCheck_pA_length * pBpA_length`.
Even if the original added code in the question got extra brackets `... > 0.9999*(pToCheck_pA.x*pBpA.x + pToCheck_pA.y*pBpA.y + ...)`, this comparison wouldn't answer anything / make any sense. It is important that the right hand side is based on the product of lengths, rather than explicitly writing out the dot product. Otherwise there is no check for the vectors being parallel.